# Asp.net access method from user control access method

Tags: asp.net

I've a user control registered in an aspx page On click event of a button in the aspx page, how do i call a method which is there in the user control?
I need to execute the method in user control on click event of button in  aspx page.

Thanks....

Comment: You have a reference to your UserControl in your Button's click-event handler? So where is the problem to call `MyUserControl.Foo()` there? This function must be `public`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Below might help

UserControl B = new UserControl();
Object[] parameters = new Object[2];
parameters[0] = 45;
parameters[1] = "test"; 
B = (UserControl)Page.FindControl("[UserControlId]");
B.GetType().GetMethod("[MethodName]").Invoke(B, parameters);
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I m getting this error.

Comment: B.GetType().GetMethod("[copyInfo]").Invoke(B, null);
In this line I m getting error

Comment: B.GetType().GetMethod("copyInfo").Invoke(B, null); remove []

Comment: How to pass parameter in the method copyinfo  B.GetType().GetMethod("copyInfo").Invoke(B, null); there are two parameters to be passed

Comment: Its working now I have commented the second line in the above code   B = (UserControl)Page.FindControl("[UserControlId]"); (this one)  Now Plz let me know how to pass parameters in the method